# C programs not giving expected results after compiling in Mac terminal

Tags: c, macos, terminal, compiler-errors, compilation

I have a project that compiles 24 C files in MacBook air terminal, each containing their own function. I created a library for these functions using ar rcs libLibrary_name.a * .o, compiled them all using gcc -c * .c, and, and ran my driver, strtester, with the command gcc -o strtester strtester.c -L. Library_name.a. While the code does not crash, three of the functions do not give the expected output within the driver, despite sample code running as expected within these files. Only these three functions of the 24 do not work, and I'm not sure why these are not compiling specifically.

```
#include "string_library.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int
all_letters(char *s)
{
    if (is_empty(s) == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    char *temp = s;
    int all_letters = 1;

//Loops through , returning 0 if we
//find a non-alphabetic character, or 1
//otherwise. Since words can have spaces between
//them, if the string is not empty we ignore
//spaces
    while (*temp != '\0') {
        if (isalpha(*temp) == 0 && (*temp) != ' ') {
            all_letters = 0;
            break;
        }
        ++temp;
    }
    return all_letters;
}
```

The above works fine in the file, but when compiled it says that "Hello World" and "Hell0 World" both do not contain all letters. Though both technically have whitespace, the code is written in a way that if the string is found to not be empty, it will check for all letters and ignore whitespace (so only numbers and special characters should return failure, which does not happen in the strtester)

```
#include "string_library.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int
is_empty(char *s)
{
    // If the string is null, it's empty
    if (s == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Checks if there are any non-whitespace characters
    while (*s != '\0') {
        if (*s != ' ') {
            return 0;
        }
        s++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Works fine in the file it was implemented in, but in the driver gives opposite results (saying empty strings such as "  " are not empty and strings like "Hello" are empty)

```
#include "string_library.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void
rm_empties(char **words)
{
    // Indexes to help us remove strings
    int total_index = 0;
    int current_index = 0;

    // Loops through until we reach the null pointer
    while (words[total_index] != NULL) {

        // Checks if the current string is not empty
        int empty = is_empty(words[total_index]);

        if (empty == 0) {
            // If it's not empty, we copy it into words
            words[current_index] = words[total_index];
            current_index++;
        }
        total_index++;
    }
    // Caps off the array with the null pointer
    words[current_index] = NULL;
}

int
main()
{
    puts("Test for rm_empties");
    char *to_empty[] = { "Hello", "World", " ", " ", "Steph", NULL };
    puts("Array before emptying:");
    int i = 0;

    while (to_empty[i] != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", to_empty[i]);
        i++;
    }
    char **s = to_empty;

    rm_empties(to_empty);
    puts("Array after emptying:");
    int j = 0;

    while (s[j] != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", s[j]);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Works fine in the file it was implemented in, but in the driver wipes the array completely. For example given the array : {"Hello", "Goodbye", " ", " ", "Yes", NULL}, it just erases all the elements instead of leaving "Hello", "Goodbye" and "Yes" (The null pointer stays to cap off the array, so that staying is fine)

Here is the testing of each function in this strtester:

```
All_Letters:
puts("Test for all letters");
char *all_test = "Hello";
char *all_test_2 = "Hell0";
int is_all_letters = all_letters(all_test);

if (is_all_letters == 1) {
    printf("All characters in %s are letters\n\n", all_test);
}
else {
    printf("All characters in %s are not letters\n\n", all_test);
}

int is_all_letters_2 = all_letters(all_test_2);

if (is_all_letters_2 == 1) {
    printf("All characters in %s are letters\n\n", all_test_2);
}
else {
    printf("All characters in %s are not letters\n\n", all_test_2);
}

is_empty:
puts("Test for is_empty");
int is_empty_1 = is_empty(" ");

printf("%d", is_empty_1);
if (is_empty_1 == 0) {
    puts("The string " "is not empty");
}
else {
    puts("The string " " " " is  empty");
}

int is_empty_2 = is_empty("Hello");

if (is_empty_2 == 0) {
    puts("The string Hello is not empty");
}
else {
    puts("The string Hello is empty");
}

Rm_empties:
puts("Test for rm_empties");
char *to_empty[] = { "Hello", "World", " ", " ", "Steph", NULL };

puts("Array before emptying:");
int i = 0;

while (to_empty[i] != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", to_empty[i]);
    i++;
}

char **s = to_empty;

rm_empties(to_empty);
puts("Array after emptying:");
int j = 0;

while (s[j] != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", s[j]);
    j++;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please edit your code directly into the question as a [mcve]. For terminology what you have is a runtime issue, or bug, not a compiling issue.

Comment: If you can put your code into Google Docs, then you can put your code in your Stack Overflow question. Your external links here are a privacy concern, as anyone who is logged in with a Google account and accesses these will be visible to you. I'm actually going to remove your links right now, and you can [edit] your question appropriately.

Comment: @user22532748 – You really _compiled them all using `gcc -c * .c`_?

Comment: I did compiled them with gcc -c * .c since this is what I was given by my instructor, and it worked alright (minus the above errors of course). Is there a better way to compile multiple files in terminal? Sometimes the terminal commands we're given do not always work on my machine, so if there is a better way I'm genuinely curious.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure why these are not compiling specifically.

They have compiled successfully. What you are describing is not a compilation error, but a logic error, or a bug.

I have made some modifications to your code, used `isspace()` in place of manual checking, replaced most calls to `printf()` with assertions, and was unable to reproduce the problems you are describing. I do not see anything particularly awry with your driver code, nor the functions themselves, so the problem lies elsewhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static bool is_empty(const char *s) 
{
    if (!s) {
        return true;
    }

    while (*s) {
        if (!isspace(*(unsigned char *)s)) {
            return false;
        }
        ++s;
    }
    return true;
}

static void rm_empties(const char **words) 
{
    size_t total_index = 0;
    size_t current_index = 0;

    while (words[total_index]) {
        bool empty = is_empty(words[total_index]);

        if (!empty) {
            words[current_index] = words[total_index];
            ++current_index;
        }
        
        ++total_index;
    }
    words[current_index] = NULL;
}

static bool is_all_letters(const char *s)
{
    if (is_empty(s)) {
        return 0;
    }

    while (*s) {
        if(!isalpha(*(unsigned char *)s) && !isspace(*(unsigned char *)s)) {
            return false;
        }
        ++s;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    assert(is_empty(""));
    assert(!is_empty("a"));
    assert(!is_empty("Hello"));

    assert(is_all_letters("bigbang"));
    assert(!is_all_letters("49ckancas#($"));
    assert(!is_all_letters("       "));
    assert(!is_all_letters("Hell0"));

    const char *sample[] = {"Hello", "World", " ", "", "Steph", NULL};
    size_t i = 0;

    puts("BEFORE: "); 
    
    while(sample[i]) {
        puts(sample[i]);
        ++i;
    }

    rm_empties(sample);
    i = 0;
    
    puts("AFTER: ");

    while(sample[i]) {
        puts(sample[i]);
        ++i;
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**:

```
$ ./str.exe
BEFORE:
Hello
World


Steph
AFTER:
Hello
World
Steph
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Terminal tends to be really finicky with little things, so I'll try these and see if that fixes my problems.